# Apache Beam - Dataflow - Serialization & state sharing

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In one of my pipelin's **`DoFn`**, I'm downloading binary files, that need to be processed by another **`DoFn`**. 
Right now once the binary file is downloaded, I also store it in GCS and I output the location of the file to my downstream **`DoFn`**. However the upload to GCS is taking quite a long time, and I'm not even sure I need that.

Is there a way to make my binary buffer available to downstream **`DoFn`** without any serialization ? I'd basically like to have the workers on the same machine, and share data through RAM. Is that possible ?

If not, am I wrong in using GCS for data sharing between **`DoFNs`** ? Can we use directly the file system ?

Comment: Maybe pass data between `DoFn`s using `PCollection<byte[]>`?

Comment: Problem is that data could be hundreds of mega bytes

Comment: I don't think "hundreds of mega bytes" will be a problem. Dataflow runner also does some fusion so the data is essentially shared through RAM in some sense.

Comment: It does it automatically ? No need to tell it to use RAM ?

Comment: Correct. Chains of DoFn's without a GroupByKey in between will typically be fused and data between them will be passed in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice here is to pass the data directly as a byte array value.  The framework should correctly handle the passing the buffer in memory between fused stages that do not contain an intervening GroupByKey.